# Array Issue with QueryBuilder Doctrine2

Tags: doctrine-orm, query-builder

I have a Problem with the Querybuilder,

```
$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('k, l')
```

-> i got a array such as

Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[id] => 15
-> ok

when i do

```
$qb->select('k.id, l.title')->add('from', 'Base\Entities\Company k')
```

i get

Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[id] => 15
[title] => 
)

-> ok

ISSUE:

When id do:

```
$qb->select('k, l.title')->add('from', 'Base\Entities\Company k')
```

i get:

Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[id] => 15

i always do $result = $query->getArrayResult(); at the End

how can i remove the array in the array? i only want title as part of the array in k (like above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's not really possible to do so, You'll have to iterate over the results to achieve this. You can read more about it in [documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.x/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#pure-and-mixed-results).